# ASPX page error Application of Viewstate MAC Failed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an aspx page that has a few fields. When the button is pressed it talks to Dynamics CRM Online and creates a record there. This error is showing when the form is used externally and seems to be only certain people that get the error - I can't replicate it on my machine. The website is hosted on Azure Websites.

I'm not sure what code I need to share, but I've tried adding the two snippets:

```
<machineKey validationKey='...' decryptionKey='...' validation='SHA1'/>
 <pages validateRequest="false"
     enableEventValidation="false"
     viewStateEncryptionMode ="Never"
    enableViewStateMac="false">
```

To the web.config but still get the error. I'm not sure where I need to go to look at resolving this.

Code running on button click:

```
protected void checkCSN(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label confirmLabel = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
        confirmLabel.Text = "Thank you for submitting the request.<br />Someone will be in touch shortly.";

        Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse(GetServiceConfiguration());
        _service = new OrganizationService(connection);
        string fetchCompany = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                                      <entity name='account'>
                                        <attribute name='accountid' />
                                        <attribute name='ownerid' />
                                        <attribute name='name' />
                                        <filter type='and'>
                                          <condition attribute='c20_uniquesupportnumber' operator='eq' value='" + csn.Text + @"' />
                                        </filter>
                                      </entity>
                                    </fetch>";

        string fetchCon = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                                                    <entity name='contact'>
                                                        <attribute name='contactid' />
                                                        <attribute name='new_teamviewerid' />
                                                        <attribute name='new_teamviewerpw' />
                                                        <attribute name='ownerid' />
                                                        <filter type='and'>
                                                          <condition attribute='emailaddress1' operator='eq' value='" + email.Text + @"' />
                                                        </filter>
                                                      </entity>
                                                    </fetch>";

        EntityCollection cl = _service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchCompany));
        if (cl.Entities.Count == 1)
        {
            EntityReference client = new EntityReference("account", (Guid)cl.Entities[0].Attributes["accountid"]);

            Entity incident = new Entity("incident");
            EntityCollection cn = _service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchCon));
            if (cn.Entities.Count > 0)
            {
                EntityReference contact = new EntityReference("contact", (Guid)cn.Entities[0].Attributes["contactid"]);

                incident["c20_contact"] = contact;
                if (cn.Entities[0].Contains("new_teamviewerid") && cn.Entities[0].Attributes["new_teamviewerid"].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    incident["c20_teamviewercode"] = cn.Entities[0].Attributes["new_teamviewerid"].ToString();
                }
                if (cn.Entities[0].Contains("new_teamviewerpw") && cn.Entities[0].Attributes["new_teamviewerpw"].ToString().Length > 0)
                {
                    incident["new_password"] = cn.Entities[0].Attributes["new_teamviewerpw"].ToString();
                }
                incident["customerid"] = client;
                incident["title"] = product.Text + " Support";
                incident["description"] = description.Text;
                incident["ownerid"] = (EntityReference)cl.Entities[0].Attributes["ownerid"];

                incident["casetypecode"] = new OptionSetValue((int)3);

                Guid incidentId = _service.Create(incident);

                Entity ins = _service.Retrieve("incident", incidentId, new ColumnSet("ticketnumber"));
                incident.Id = incidentId;
                incident["title"] = product.SelectedItem + " Support: " + ins.Attributes["ticketnumber"].ToString();
                _service.Update(incident);
            }
            else
                confirmLabel.Text = "Invalid email address. Please contact your administrator.";

        }
        else if (cl.Entities.Count == 0)
            confirmLabel.Text = "No matching accounts with that support number. Please contact your administrator.";
        else
            confirmLabel.Text = "Invalid number of matching accounts with that support number. Please contact your administrator.";

        confirmPanel.Controls.Add(confirmLabel);
    }
```

Full Tracing. Apologies if I've removed anything important.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

Source Error: 


The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one of the below steps, then request the URL:

1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:

<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

or:

2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your application:

<configuration>
 <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>

Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.

Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.  

Stack Trace: 

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: ....
Port: 1094
Referer: http://domain.azurewebsites.net/CreateCase
Path: /CreateCase
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
ViewState: ...]

[HttpException (0x80004005): Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.]
System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +116
System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose) +432
 System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Deserialize(String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +8
System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +40
System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +248
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +272
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +36
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6704
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,  Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
ASP.createcase_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +37
  System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET     Version:4.0.30319.36215
```

Comment: Not certain, hence I won't post it as an answer, but I suspect the key being used to validate the viewstate and generate the MAC is not consistent over round trips due to the Azure hosting. Either that, or the affected clients are doing something on their end to alter the viewstate prior to submit that is causing the MAC failure.

Comment: I don't think the clients would be doing anything 'deliberate' so it would be something I need to handle. Is it possible to test whether the key is constent?

Comment: Oh, no, I did not mean the *users*, I meant client in terms of client *machines.* MAC validation is done behind the scenes. You might explore specification of a constant machine key to check this possibility

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - my bad. Would the `<machineKey ... />` item in system.web handle this because it's still giving the error with that in there

Comment: I used a key generated from here: http://www.orcsweb.com/articles/generate-aspnet-machine-key/ could that be causing an issue?

Comment: It's possible, but I would think it would be an issue only if the key itself were somehow corrupt or incorrectly generated. As long as that key specifically is placed in the config file, guaranteeing its consistency behind a farm, that's probably not the issue, then - unless there's some peculiar web.config transform that somehow excludes it when published to Azure?!?! (Complete straw-grasp there)

Comment: Possibly not then - I've tried a different one and it still fails. Would it help to share my whole config and then generate new keys?

Comment: Could it be the .net version? The generators mention 1.1 and 2.0 but my solution is 4.5.2

Comment: If I were you, I think I'd generate some new, clean machine keys, ensuring I create them to match the hosting environment. Then I would go through the steps at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218 as a baseline that also talks about some application level issues that might be in play here. Give those a shot.